# airflow : wait to receive email and process data contained in attached file

Tags: python-3.x, email, airflow

I am looking for a wait to schedule tasks based on the reception of an email.

More precisely, I received an email with some attached data every week and I need to add these data into a database (and process some information). Is there a way to do it automatically?

Would airflow be a good option to do this? I found that airflow can send email but I did not find anything about reading mails.

I know it is possible to read email and download attached file in python. But what would be the best way to check if a specific email is received (defined by a sender) and process its data as soon as it is received ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Airflow is a great option for this workflow.

Airflow has the concept of SensorOperators which are derived from the [BaseSensorOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html?highlight=sensor#basesensoroperator). Using a SensorOperator will allow you to easily control the poke_interval and timeout of the task as well as how to handle the various situations depending on whether or not the email arrives as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule some `BashOperator` or `PythonOperator` that periodically checks new mail and if they find one they start processing it. While I cannot give you any specific library, I am sure there must be a way to read and handle email in Python.